# Dynamic programming - maximum sum increasing sub sequence

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

Given an array of n positive integers. this is a program to find the sum of maximum sum subsequence of the given array such that the integers in the subsequence are in increasing order. I am trying to implement the code based on this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99ssGWhLPUE&index=27&list=PLrmLmBdmIlpsHaNTPP_jHHDx_os9ItYXr)
I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
 class MaxIncreasingSumSubSequence(object):
        def incsum(self,nums):
            maxvalue = 0
            sumlist = nums
            for i in range(1,len(nums)):
                for j in range(i):
                    if nums[j] < nums[i] and nums[i] + sumlist[j] > sumlist[i]:
                        sumlist[i] = nums[i] + sumlist[j]
            maxvalue = max(sumlist)
            print(maxvalue)

MaxIncreasingSumSubSequence().incsum([1, 101, 2, 3, 100, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, when you do `list1 = list2`, you don't get two lists. `list1` becomes a reference of `list2`. Essentially the two variables refer to the same list.

So change it to `list1 = list2[:]` to *copy* the values from one list to another. The following should work:

```
def incsum(nums):
    sumlist = nums[:]
    for i in range(1,len(nums)):
        for j in range(0,i):
            if nums[j] < nums[i] and nums[i] + sumlist[j] > sumlist[i]:
                sumlist[i] = nums[i] + sumlist[j]
    print(max(sumlist))

incsum([1, 101, 2, 3, 100, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(a):
    n=len(a)
    list_sum=[a[0]]
    max_val=a[0]
    for i in range(1,n):
        temp=a[i]
        j=i-1
        while j>-1:
            if a[j]<a[i]:
                if temp<a[i]+list_sum[j]:
                    temp=a[i]+list_sum[j]
                if list_sum[j]==max_val:
                    break

            j-=1
        list_sum.append(temp)
        if temp>max_val:
            max_val=temp

    return max_val
 fun(array)
```